# Do not continue when duplicate items are found in Prolog

Tags: prolog

The idea is to define a predicate that counts how many times an element appears in a list, but that the recursion stops when there are 2 occurrences of the element.

```
contElemen(_,[],0).
contElemen(X,[X|T],N):-contElemen(X,T,N1), N is N1 + 1.
contElemen(X,[_|T],N):- contElemen(X,T,N).
```

I do not know if I'm understanding everything wrong in prolog, is it possible to stop execution (without break) when N = 2?

Obviously, I'm new to prolog, sorry if the question is incorrect. Thank you

Comment: This is an execution, I need N to not go over 2. `?- contElemen(2,[2,2,2,2,2],N).
N = 5 .
`

Comment: Prolog is a declarative language not an imperative one. Early termination is very imperative...

Comment: Exactly 2 or not more than 2? For the latter, you need a condition somewhere, `N =< 2`.

Comment: Exactly 2 @lurker

Comment: @MarioL Then it is obviously impossible. When you find 2 elements you must make sure there are no more. You can terminate early if you count more than 2, for example (negative case).

Comment: It's okay, so it's not possible, and my problem is understanding. And how could I do that @EugeneSh.? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: A query such as `contElemen(x, [1,2,x,3,x,4], 3).` wouldn't make sense if you're incrementing `N` in your code. Rather than increment `N` you should decrement `N` and succeed only if your base case is reached `contElemen(_, [], 0)`. Any other clause should ensure `N > 0` on each recursive call. Your 3rd clause must ensure that the first element of the list is not `X`. It can't just use `_`. Otherwise you'll lose proper count of how many `X` you encountered.

Comment: I could not have explained it better. Thank you. What I was looking for is that the recursion will dent when I find at least 2 occurrences of the same element. For example, if I have the list [1,2,3,4,4,5], let the recursion stop after evaluating the second occurrence of element 4, which does not evaluate values ​​3, 2 and 1.

Comment: Right, but because you're looking for exactly two 4s, you must continue with recursion after seeing the second element `4` in order to determine that there are no more element `4` in the list, at least until you either see another `4` (fail) or get to the end of the list (succeed).

Comment: Perfect, now I understand my confusion. Regards ! @lurker